# Running a docker image on two windows hosts with different build number

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerhub

I am running a docker image with base image

```
 tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine
```

I want to access a rest api service through tomcat.
Running the docker image on a host with windows 10 pro build number 1909, the rest api service runs successfully.
Running the docker image on a host with windows 10 pro build number 1809, the java classes are not getting scanned by jersey.
`com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found`  line with the java classes initiated never appears in logs.

**Question:** Is it possible to have this different behavior of the same docker image on hosts that differ only on the build number of windows?

**EDIT:**

1. docker-compose file is  [here](https://github.com/SODALITE-EU/semantic-reasoner/blob/master/source%20code/semantic-reasoner/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: No. It should be a different issue. The USP of docker will be violated if it differs in functionality from host-to-host. That being said, there can be changes in ways in which docker-machine VM is running. `docker run` command might be bound to some volume which can cause this. Please add more information to the question about the commands being run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean that the behavior of dockers does not change from host to host, but what it matters is the way we run the dockers (parameters e.t.c.).
For example, when I run the docker image in the same way on windows with build number 1909, classes getting initialized:

15-Jul-2020 07:49:38.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes
class restapi.TestReasonerService
class restapi.PropertyService
...
While on windows with build number 1809, the java classes are not getting initialized

Comment: I edited the description by adding the docker-compose file. I do not use docker  volumes so I guess no docker run has been bound to any volume

Comment: I see in your dockerfile that you're copying the contents of `./reasoner-api/target/reasoner-api.war` into your container. Are the contents of this war file the same from one windows host to another?

Comment: I compared the WEB-INF/lib folder of wars and they are the same. Finally it worked by adding FROM tomcat:7.0.103-jdk8-corretto. It is weird because docker was running correctly one one host with tomcat8 or 9. By using tomcat 7, it can run on all hosts

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked by adding

> FROM tomcat:7.0.103-jdk8-correto

It is weird that the jersey classes were initiated correctly with tomcat 8 or 9 base image on one host and not on others. Also, without using dockers, the application runs correctly with tomcat 8 or 9. With tomcat 7 docker image above, docker is running correctly on all hosts. However, I cannot explain this different behavior per host.